# How to draw this 3D picture ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: quad]
i am working first time in latex, i don't know how to draw 3D diagram in latex. please some one help me how to draw this picture.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Something to get you started: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42812/18228, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138960/how-to-draw-this-picture-in-3d-tikz, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61880/3d-image-using-tikz.

Comment: related reading: [policy on “how do I draw this?” questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/policy-on-how-do-i-draw-this-questions)

Comment: Please add more details what is exactly that you need help to cope with! Even some more specifications of "how this image is 3D" might help.